# tcsh vs zsh. Escape/control characters

Tags: zsh, quoting, special-characters

I am having problems running this command to work in zsh:

```
my_command -u something -s X:^0
```

The command works right away on tcsh, but on zsh I get:

```
zsh: no matches found -s X:^0
```

This made me wonder if `^` is to blame. As far as I understand `sX:^0` is the value of the argument `-s`, but zsh seems to expand it and not pass it to `my_command` in the same way tcsh would do.

Is my understanding correct? If so how can I run the same command in zsh?

Comment: Is the command really called "command"? `command` in a shell built-in in ZSH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `extendedglob` enabled, in zsh, `^` is a the negation globbing operator, so `-sX:^0` means *any filename starting with `-sX:` not followed by `0`*.

You need to quote it (as in `'-sX:^0'` or `-sX:\^0` or `-s"X:^0"`...) if you don't want it to be interpreted as a globbing operator.

Note that in the Bourne shell and its predecessors, `^` was also a *pipe* operator so needed quoted as well.

Comment: Thanks. How exactly should I quote this to get the same behavior as in tcsh? Should I fully quote `-sX:^0`?